# Swift must use lazy for stored property when use self in closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I create subclass for UITableViewCell, and want to add UILabel for subview. I use the stored property for get UILabel, like this

```
class ZXArtistListCell: UITableViewCell {
  lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    self.contentView.addSubview(view)
    return view
  }()
}
```

but ,when I delete `lazy` or replace `lazy var` with `let`, it's give me error,

> Value of type'(NSObject) -> ZXArtistCell' has no member 'contentView'

So, What's that meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are declaring label with lazy **initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used**.
so the probably the Instantiates views was completed.

But the concept of using let in Swift, variables which are `let` have to be initialized before you can use `self`.

Using `lazy var` means that the compiler can verify that the value assigned to label won't be accessed before self is a valid object, because it won't be possible to call label until all other members of the class have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var
>   keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after
>   instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always
>   have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be
>   declared as lazy.

[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)